# BIRT Column Width not being Respected

Tags: css, html-table, birt

I'm trying to create a BIRT report.  The code and query side of it works just fine, but the display is rather wonky.

There's one column whose text contents are rather long, and instead of showing some text and allowing scrolling of the text (which is the behavior I'd like there), it simply shows up as a *very* vertically long text block; kinda ruins the report a bit.  I've also tried setting the width on the column, but no dice there either.  Any ideas?

Also, as an aside, how do I get the table's columns to have grid lines?  I can do that on the rows, but I can't seem to figure out how to do that for the columns.  If anyone has insight into that issue, it'd be appreciated.

Here's a screenshot of the issue

[image]

[Here's my BIRT report XML, without headers and footers in order reduce characters](http://freetexthost.com/sb31mtcgou)

Comment: Please include your code in the question. Linking to it via an external site is not enough for us to help you.

Comment: i did include code.  it's a large xml file, which stackoverflow will not allow me to paste; that's why i put it on a text hosting site - how is that not enough?  is there another way for me to include that xml in a way that the community would prefer?

Comment: Yes, include just enough XML that is required to reproduce your error. Check out [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for info on that.

Comment: yea, i cannot do what you're asking.  look at the xml to which i linked, tell me what i can cut out.  the entirety of the xml is needed to reproduce the issue.  not sure what else i can do.  and really, not sure why linking to the hosted xml is insufficient for you to be able to help me.

Comment: Some users may still choose to help you, but it's simply the rule that you need to include your code *in the question*. Linking to code means that, once your link dies, your question is effectively unanswerable/not useful to future readers.

Comment: i do understand that, and i hope that someone does help me.  i always try to adhere to the rules and guidelines of the community, but in this instance, i do not know how i can do that.  if i find a better way to ask this question, i will definitely go that route, but i just don't see how to do that right now, even after reading your linked help article.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107761/discussion-between-liltitus27-and-tylerh).

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way to use a scrollable view element inside your report, because the output by the default html-emitter is completely static (I would like to see a different answer if this should be wrong).

To your second Question about how to add a border to a column. Click into the cell of your table, click on "Border" inside the "Properties Editor" and select the borders you like to use. This should be repreated for all cells where you want to use the borders, because this configuration is not applied for a whole column but just for one cell. If you want a border for the whole column you need to setup the border for every cell in the column.

If you have already a data cell inside your table cell, you can use the outline view to select the table cell instead of the data cell:

[image]

Comment: While this answer is certainly correct, it only addresses the "grid lines" part of the question. The "column width ignored" part is still unanswered. But without the code that will probably remain unanswered.